# sort dictionary in the reverse order

Tags: python, dictionary

```
my_dict = {1: {'f1': 'name', 'f2': 'age', 'f3': 'class'}, 2: {'f1': 'company', 'f2': 'salary', 'f3': 'age', 'f4': 'class'}, 3: {'f1': 'Feature', 'f2': 'sum', 'f3': 'diff', 'f4': 'multiply', 'f5': 'div', 'f6': 'and', 'f7': 'or', 'f8': 'not', 'f9': 'dummy'}}
```

I need Reverse of this as

```
my_dict = { 3: {'f1': 'Feature', 'f2': 'sum', 'f3': 'diff', 'f4': 'multiply', 'f5': 'div', 'f6': 'and', 'f7': 'or', 'f8': 'not', 'f9': 'dummy'},2: {'f1': 'company', 'f2': 'salary', 'f3': 'age', 'f4': 'class'},1: {'f1': 'name', 'f2': 'age', 'f3': 'class'}, }
```

I tried using
sorted,Ordereddict,reverse functions on dictionary but its not working

Comment: OrderedDict just remembers the insertion order of the keys, so you could start with your dict you already have and insert its (key,value) pairs in the correct order in a new OrderedDict

Answer (score 0):

`OrderedDict` only remembers the insertion order, and a dict has no order, so you must construct your `OrderedDict` from a list of tuples (or insert the values one by one after constructing the ord. dict):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> od = OrderedDict([(3, 'three'), (2, 'two'), (1, 'one')])
>>> od
OrderedDict([(3, 'three'), (2, 'two'), (1, 'one')])
```

As you can see, the order is maintained.

If you need *both* orders, we can loop through the `key, value` pairs using `od.items()`, and we can reverse the order of those pairs using `reversed`:

```
>>> reversed_od = OrderedDict(reversed(od.items()))
>>> reversed_od
OrderedDict([(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three')])
```

Answer (score -1):

Python dict is unordered, it means that you can't manage elements order. The only way to do this is OrderedDict instead of dict.

If you want to store data from your dict sorted descending by key this is IMO the easiest method:

```
OrderedDict(sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda t: t[0], reverse=True))
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) you can read more about OrderedDict.